# How to autofocus Quill Editor in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, text-editor, quill

I'm using `quill` with `vue 3` and can't find a way to autofocus the editor input field in their [docs](https://vueup.github.io/vue-quill/).

I've tried targeting parent elements with:

```
document.getElementById(...).focus()
```

which did nothing. This is how I've implemented quill, **`text-editor.vue`**:

```
<template>
  <div id="text-editor" class="text-editor">
    <quill-editor :modules="modules" :toolbar="toolbar"/>
  </div>
</template>


<script setup>
import BlotFormatter from 'quill-blot-formatter'

const modules = {
    module: BlotFormatter,
}

const toolbar = [
    [{ 'header': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, false] }],
    [{ 'size': ['small', false, 'large', 'huge'] }],
    ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike'],
    ['blockquote', 'code-block'],
    [{ 'align': [] }],
    [{ 'list': 'ordered'}, { 'list': 'bullet' }],
    [{ 'color': [] }, { 'background': [] }],
    [{ 'font': [] }],
    ['link', 'image', 'video'],
    ['clean']
];
</script>
```

and import it in **`component.vue`**:

```
<template>
  <div id="component">
    <text-editor/>
  </div>
</template>


<script setup>
import textEditor from './text-editor'
</script>
```

Any idea how to `autofocus` quill?

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution. Just use the @onReady event. As simple as this:

```
    <QuillEditor
    theme="snow"
    @ready="onReady"
  />
```

Then add the method:

```
 methods: {
    onReady(editor) {
      editor.focus();
    },
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access the `quill` instance with `getQuill()` API and then use `quill.focus()` to focus the quill editor, here is an example:

```
<template>
  <QuillEditor 
    ref="quillEditor"
    theme="snow"
    :options="options"
    @ready="onQuillReady"
  />
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from "vue";
import { QuillEditor } from "@vueup/vue-quill";
import "@vueup/vue-quill/dist/vue-quill.snow.css";

const quillEditor = ref(); // editor ref
const options = {
  // ... options for quill editor ...
}

function onQuillReady() {
  // focus editor when it is ready
  quillEditor.value.getQuill().focus();
}
</script>
```

Ref: https://vueup.github.io/vue-quill/api/methods.html#getquill